# Find the triple integral of $f(x,y,z)=(x^8+y^6+z^4)$sin$(z^3)+2y-3$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the triple integral of $f(x,y,z)=(x^8+y^6+z^4)$sin$(z^3)+2y-3$ over the unit ball. I am completely stuck. I have tried converting to cylindrical and spherical coordinates and neither seems to help. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @nbubis I am unfamiliar with this method. I googled it and it seems to be a method to find an approximation for the integral. Is that right? I need the exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first half of the function is proportional to $\sin(z^3)$ which is odd, and since for every choice of $x,y$ the interval of integration over $z$ is symmetric, the integral over the first part is equal to $0$. The same logic holds for $2y$. So now you just need to calculate:
$$\int_B -3 \ \ dx dy dz = -3V = -4\pi$$

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand now I have worked it through myself.